# Is there a way to ignore elements in an array without changing the array in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that checks if two arrays have the same elements even if they aren't sorted, but I I can't change the arrays and I can't copy them or use a third/fourth arrays and it has to be recursive, lastly, I can't change the signature of the function.

So now I have to get rid of `overwrite(A2, len, i);` because that's destroying `A2`, but I don't see any way to do it and still have a working function... can I have a hint on how to do it? Maybe there's a way to save the elements of `A2` by swapping them and then by the end of the recursion to restore them?

In short the algorithm below does a linear search of the last element of A1 in A2, if it's found, overwrite it and continue, this is done so the algorithm won't pick the same element twice, reaching the stopping condition means all the elements are there thus it will return true, otherwise will return false.

```
bool foo(int A1[], int A2[], int len){//both arrays are size len

    int i;
    bool found = false;

    if (len == 0)return true;//stopping condition for recursion
    else{
        for (i = 0; i < len && !found; i++)//linear search
            if (A1[len - 1] == A2[i]){
                overwrite(A2, len, i);//this function shifts back the whole array
                found = true;
            }

        if (found == false) return false;
        else foo(A1, A2, len - 1);

    }
}
```

Sample i/o:

```
A1:    3   2   1
A2:    1   2   3
True

A1:    3   2   3
A2:    1   2   3
False
```

Comment: If you post sample input and expected output, someone might be able to help.

Comment: It is impossible to do this in a sane way sticking to your requirements. In fact, I'd wager it's downright impossible to do, unless you have the ability to create arrays. It looks like a misunderstanding of the assignment to me.

Comment: What would be your expected result for `[ 2 1 3 3 ]` and `[ 1 1 3 2 ]`? true or false?

Comment: @aib no it's exactly how they specified the assignment, we can't use any other arrays and can't change the given arrays. Maybe there's a way to change the arrays and then by the end return them to how they were?

Comment: @Stephen false, they don't have the same elements.

Comment: @aib: I think it can be done. Not very efficently but it's even O(1) in space if the compiler implements tail recursion.

Comment: @6502: Hmm, working in sorting order instead of actually sorting the arrays. Nice! Great answer. So I lost my wager... But I'd still like to retain the "sane way" part of my comment, if it's okay :)

Comment: @kuhaku: This doesn't answer your question but [`std::is_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) in the standard library does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works given all your requirements. It rearranges the arrays, and then un-rearranges them. It uses recursion, uses no additional arrays, and does not change the function signature.

```
bool foo(int A1[], int A2[], int len){

    int i;
    if (len == 0){
        return true;

    } else {

        for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){

            if (A1[len - 1] == A2[i]){

                A2[i] = A2[len - 1];
                A2[len - 1] = A1[len - 1];

                bool result = foo(A1, A2, len - 1);

                A2[len - 1] = A2[i];
                A2[i] = A1[len - 1];

                return result;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `A2[len - 1] = A1[len - 1];` and `A2[i] = A1[len - 1];` parts are needed? (it didn't work without them in another example I just tried...)

Comment: @kuhaku They are rearranging the variables around so that they can be replaced back into their original order before the recursion completes.

Comment: Just an FYI both `A2[len - 1] = A1[len - 1];`, `A2[len - 1] = A2[i];` can be removed and it'll still work, probably because in each level of recursion the element is already the last one in `A1`. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Considering that is not using tail-recursion, this will explode into quite a few function calls (as many as `len`) which is probably unwanted. It might be cheaper to create a copy sort that and use binary search...

Answer (score 5):

A solution could be:

1. find what is the maximum value `M` in in `A1` and how many times it appears
2. check if it's the same for `A2`, including the count
3. find what is the maximum value `M1` among all values smaller than `M` and how many times is present in A1
4. check if it's the same for `A2`, including the count
5. find what is the maximum value `M2` among all values smaller than `M1` and how many times is present in A1
6. check if it's the same for `A2`, including the count
7. repeat this way until the counter for `A1` and `A2` is zero or is different

in code:

```
bool checkSame(int *A1, int *A2, int len) {
    struct Same {
        static bool check(int *A1, int *A2, int len, int limit) {
            int index1=-1, count1=0;
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if (A1[i] <= limit) {
                    if (index1==-1 || A1[i] > A1[index1]) {
                        index1 = i;
                        count1 = 1;
                    } else if (A1[i] == A1[index1]) {
                        count1++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int index2=-1, count2=0;
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if (A2[i] <= limit) {
                    if (index2==-1 || A2[i] > A2[index2]) {
                        index2 = i;
                        count2 = 1;
                    } else if (A2[i] == A2[index2]) {
                        count2++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (index1 == -1 && index2 == -1) return true;
            if (count1 != count2 || count1 == 0 ||
                A1[index1] != A2[index2]) return false;
            return check(A1, A2, len, A1[index1]-1);
        }
    };
    return Same::check(A1, A2, len, INT_MAX);
}
```

This algorithm is O(n^2) in time (worst case: arrays are identical and all values unique) and requires constant space if the compiler supports tail call optimization.

The following is a chart for the time needed in ms from 0 to 3000 elements on my PC.

[image]

Note that however all this is not a decent solution for the problem but just an exercise in futility. A real solution of course would need more context as there are different criteria for optimality, but I'd probably go for a closed hash table... adding elements while processing A1 and removing elements processing A2 (the removal will fail at some point if and only if the arrays are different):

```
bool checkSame2(int *A1, int *A2, int len) {
    std::vector<int> ht(len, -1), next(len, -1);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        int k = (unsigned)A1[i]*69069 % len;
        next[i] = ht[k]; ht[k] = i;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        int k = (unsigned)A2[i]*69069 % len;
        int prev=-1,p=ht[k];
        while (p!=-1 && A1[p] != A2[i]) {
            prev = p; p = next[p];
        }
        if (p == -1) return false;
        if (prev == -1) ht[k] = next[p]; else next[prev] = next[p];
    }
    return true;
}
```

The execution time for this solution is the purple line touching the N axis in the previous chart (hard to tell with this scale but it's linear + noise, as expected).

Just out of curiosity I also tried what would be the solution if "optimal" means just getting something working that is not hideous:

```
bool checkSame3(int *A1, int *A2, int len) {
    std::map<int, int> counts;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) counts[A1[i]]++;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (--counts[A2[i]] < 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is, unsurprisingly, about 30-40 times slower than the hand-coded hash table version on my PC (but of course still much faster than the recursive version).

Comment: `A1[i] < A1[index1]` shouldn't that be the other way around? Since you're looking for a maximum? Also, when you do find a new max, shouldn't it be `count1 = 1`, not 0?

Comment: This is potentially N^2, right? (All unique values, you do N passes detecting the Nth largest element)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: yes, O(n^2) in time and O(1) in space (if the compiler supports tail call optimization).

Comment: … assuming that the arrays are small, and that memory is in general large, I would have created copies, sorted them and then run linear compare for O(N log N) time at O(N) space cost. If the compiler does not support tail call optimization you can trivially change the code to be iterative instead of recursive (make it a loop, modify the second argument at the end of the loop)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: This is not real coding... the requirement were for not allocating other arrays and for using recursion (whatever that may mean). Of course it depends on the data but if speed is the discriminant I'd probably go for a hand-coded closed hash table solution (adding elements of A1 and then removing elements while processing A2). In a quick experiment processing 3000 elements requires 0.036ms instead of 23.012ms of this recursive nonsense approach and, excluding pathological input for hash collisions, is O(N) in both size and time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to *temporarily* change the arrays, provided that you restore them before the last recursive call has returned, you can swap the matching element in `A2` with the element at index `len - 1` before the recursive call, and swap them back afterwards. Since the recursive call will only look at the index range `0` through `len - 2`, the matching element will not be considered.

Comment: I thought of that, but it doesn't go back to being sorted in the same way... i.e: http://pastebin.com/UthJzcPa

Comment: You should swap with `len - 1`, not `size - 1`; otherwise, a previously matched element will get swapped back in. Also, you might want to break out of the loop once you have found a match.